# Eclipse Java formatter not aligning columns

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

My bug is that the formatter doesn't align columns properly. It does the opposite.
So I have "Align fields in columns" checked in a profile based on Eclipse built-in 2.1. That's the only modification I made. (I can see the code properly spaced in the example, I didn't forget to click apply).

My code formats like this (example 1):

```
int test1 = 1;
int testtest = 2;
int testtesttest = 3;
```

Instead of (example 2):

```
int test1          =    1;
int testtest       =    2;
int testtesttest   =    3;
```

Even when I manually change it, Ctrl-Shift-F realign it as example 1. I tried changing some other random settings to make it work but no luck. I also went in Appearance to change the font to consolas everywhere.

This morning the formatter was working fine. The bug started after, as suggested by a colleague, I tried the google java style. So I downloaded the XML and imported it into Eclipse. I didn't like it so I went back to Eclipse built-in with align columns but it doesn't align columns anymore.

I searched a lot on this and it's really bugging me. I'm not sure where I did something wrong and how to revert back to my old code format. I also tried manually changing most of the code in another file, no joy.

Comment: Example 2 doesn't follow java code convention. Why you need it?

Comment: Why would you spend pointless time on formatting code like this? As @Divers mentioned, this doesn't follow standard code convention

Comment: Most of the project I'm working on was formatted with aligned colums. I wanted to keep it like it. Anyway I found out how. I'll post answer.

Comment: @trixrabbit Most of the projects? Wow, can't believe - I thought it possible only in php world. Please send this link to authors of that projects - http://web.archive.org/web/20140228225807/http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Comment: I guess the author won't really care. It's a 10 y/o project that I had to modify for during my internship. It's a little web tool used within our intranet. Thank you for correcting me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem :

In Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter in the top right I clicked "Configure Project Specific Settings..." and changed my project to the right profile.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter

select the active profile as **GoogleStyle**.

How to install googleStyle in Eclipse

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml

Eclipse default is Eclipse[built-in] and you can import setting from following links

[image]

**Helpful links**

- https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcodestyle%2Fref-preferences-formatter.htm
- http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-share-my-code-formatting-settings-with-another-user.html?page=2